# How to check if a process is up on a remote windows in java

Tags: java, windows, remote-access

I'm looking for a solution to check if a windows service is active from a java remote application.
There is a library in java with practical examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
sc \\<servername> query <servicename>
```